# How to delete empty datagridview cells on import

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Currently I have my program hiding blank or empty datagridview cells. I want to find a way to delete these cells entirely. The reason being, after the blank cells were hidden they would reappear after going through some of my other validations. These validations checked to see if the cells contained any invalid input such as negative numbers,non-numeric input and blank cells. If they contained any of the above they would be populated with default values, thus making my hidden cells reappear. Hopefully if there is a way to delete these cells they won't have a change of getting filled with default data. I've found the below code on MSDN but it doens't seem to work properly for whatever reason. Also I'm using the DATABINDINGCOMPLETE event. I'm not sure if there is another event that would work better for this situation. I greatly appreciate any help you may give!

```
   Private Sub DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataBindingComplete


    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim mtCell As Integer = 0
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For j = 1 To row.Cells.Count -2
            If row.Cells(j).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                mtCell += 1
            End If
        Next
        If mtCell = row.Cells.Count Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
        i += 1
        mtCell = 0
    Next

end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various problems with your code. Here you have an improved version which should work without any problem:

```
Dim mtCell As Integer = 0
Dim row As DataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow()
For rowNo As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 To 0 Step -1
    row = DataGridView1.Rows(rowNo)
    Try
        For j = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 2 
            If row.Cells(j).Value Is Nothing OrElse row.Cells(j).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                mtCell += 1
            End If
        Next
        If mtCell = row.Cells.Count - 1 Then 'I understand that you want to delete the row ONLY if all its cells are null 
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowNo)
        End If
        mtCell = 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit For
    End Try
Next rowNo
```

First thing, it is better to iterate the Collection "backwards" when deleting in order to avoid problems (example: 3 rows; you delete the first position and the loop goes to the second one; but after the deletion all the rows "move up" and thus the second position is now occupied by the third row -> you would skip the second row and, eventually, iterate beyond the limits of the Collection). `DBNull.Value` is quite restrictive; not sure if it is working fine under your specific conditions, but better complementing it with `Nothing`. You cannot affect the item being iterated in a `For Each` loop (unlikely in a normal `For` one); in this case you are affecting it indirectly but just to make sure, better relying on a normal For loop. You are iterating through rows but you are not deleting these rows, but the ones defined by a counter (`i`) which is not necessarily related to the current row number, better getting rid of it. Lastly I have included a `try...catch` to make sure (that you don't access an inexistent position).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting an index out of bounds exception, I can't figure out why.

Comment: @stackexchange12 this is a sample code which you should adapt to your specific situation. In any case, this is a pretty in-the-safest-side scenario and cannot see where this error might be triggered; the only option I can think of is your datagridview not containing data at all. Please, confirm that the control contains data (and give me a sample to take a look) and the line where the error is triggered.

Comment: Yes you are right. For the most part my excel worksheet is blank, but I'm trying to delete these blank rows without having to resize my select statement.

Comment: @stackexchange12 You are mixing up things; this code does not have nothing to with Excel, just with DataDridView1 and thus it can/cannot work properly depending upon the contents you are inputting to DataGridView1 (it should deal fine with any size). Understand what this site is about and the intention of my help: you should be a programmer with a specific problem, having the required knowledge and will to maximise my help and fix it by your own (while keeping this question as generic as possible for others). I can help you though but you have to provide the right information...

Comment: @stackexchange12 that is, the contents of DataGridView1 (the only thing which matters to this specific code). But I insist that I shouldn't be doing this and thus you have to make an effort such that this process will be short and easy (for me); otherwise, I would delete this answer and stop helping you. Also, in the future, try to use this site as it is intended to be used: punctual questions when you have a more or less solid knowledge on the specific matter.

Comment: Yes you are completely right. So sorry about this. I finally got it working for my situation. Best of luck to you and happy coding.

Comment: @stackexchange12 no problem at all. I am happy to read that you finally made it work.